# Analyze and find the solution Un in $u_k=u_{k−1}+k^2$ recurrence relation in terms of Big Theta

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am trying to analyze this recurrence relation in terms of Big Theta.
Why $\Theta(N^2)$ is wrong answer? My thought is that while the answer for a similar problem is $u_k=u_{k−1}+1 = \Theta(N)$ then the answer for the problem above must be $\Theta(N^2).$ I am following the method of finding the $\Theta$ in a non recurrence function.

Comment: Well following your pattern wouldn't $u_k=u_{k-1}+k$ be $\Theta(N^2)$ and $u_k=u_{k-1}+k^2$ be $\Theta(N^3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see for yourself, expand your recurrence relation:

$$
\begin{align}
    u_k &= u_{k-1} + k^2 \\
        &= \underbrace{u_{k-2} + (k-1)^2}_{= u_{k-1}} + k^2 \\
        &= \underbrace{u_{k - 3} + (k - 2)^2}_{= u_{k-2}} + (k - 1)^2 + k^2 \\
        &= \underbrace{u_{k - 4} + (k - 3)^2}_{= u_{k-3}} + (k-2)^2 + (k - 1)^2 + k^2 \\
    & \vdots \\
    u_k &= u_0 + \sum_{i=0}^k (k - i)^2  \\
        &= u_0 + \frac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1)}{6} \\
        &= u_0 + \frac{k^3 + \mbox{terms dominated by } k^3}{6}
\end{align}
$$
which, assuming $u_0$ takes constant time, is essentially $\mathcal{\Theta}(k^3)$. Remember that $T(n) = \Theta(n^3)$ is implied by

$$
c_1 n^3 \leq T(n) \leq c_2 n^3
$$
for appropriately small $c_1$ and large $c_2$, which is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is helpful but I am not getting why the summation ∑i=0k(k−i)2 and also I don't understand how you end with Θ(k3). Can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: @peterpanx I added a few more terms in the answer, if it helps you. To see why the final sum appears, ask yourself: how many times do you have to "reduce" $k$ until you reach $0$? For the $i$'th of those steps, you get a quadratic cost $(k - i)^2$. Those costs make up the final sum.

Comment: yes it is much clearer now. According to this rules here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/551391/413117 the summation should be k(k+1)(2k+1)/6 .What it is changed here? Also,in our case which is c1 and accordingly c2? Thanks a lot again for the help!

Comment: @peterpanx You were right, I had a typo. I edited the answer to add the correct result. For $c_2$, observe that $k(k+1)(2k+1) / 6=\frac{2k_3+3k_2+k}{6} \leq \frac{6 k_3}{6}$ for large $k$, so you could pick $c_2 = 1$. For $c_1$, observe that $ \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} \geq \frac{2k^3}{6} $, so you can pick $c_1 = \frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems easier to me to solve the recurrence and analyze the solution.

First we try to get rid of the inhomogenity:
$$
u_k = u_{k-1} + k^2 \\
$$
Then for $k+1$ we have
$$
u_{k+1} = u_k + (k+1)^2 \\
$$
Then subtracting the first equation from the second and rearranging gives
$$
u_{k+1} = 2 u_k - u_{k-1} + 2k + 1 \\
u_{k+2} = 2 u_{k+1} - u_k + 2k + 3
$$
and subtracting again gives
$$
u_{k+2} = 3 u_{k+1} - 3 u_k + u_{k-1} + 2 \\
u_{k+3} = 3 u_{k+2} - 3 u_{k+1} + u_k + 2
$$
and finally
$$
u_{k+3} = 4 u_{k+2} - 6 u_{k+1} + 4 u_k - u_{k-1}
$$
or
$$
u_n = 4 u_{n-1} - 6 u_{n-2} + 4 u_{n-3} - u_{n-4}
$$
This is a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients and characteristic polynomial
$$
p(t) = t^4 -4 t^3 + 6 t^2 - 4 t + 1 = (t-1)^4
$$
with four fold root $r=1$ and thus the solution is of the form
\begin{align}
u_n 
&= k_1 r^n + k_2 n r^n + k_3 n^2 r^n + k_4 n^3 r^n \\
&= k_1 + k_2 n + k_3 n^2 + k_4 n^3
\end{align}
The four constants $k_i$ depend on the initial values $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$.

Thus $u_n = \Theta(n^3)$.